# How do I create my secret awsconfiguration.json in CI?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-amplify, bitrise

I've been using AWS amplify to build my iOS app's backend.

I have created 4 DTAP environments in the backend, with 4 different configurations, and use a run-script to switch in the correct versions of `awsconfiguration.json` and `amplifyconfiguration.json` at compile-time based on the selected scheme.

Since these auto-generated config files contain a number of secrets and API keys, I am keeping them away from source control in my .gitignore as this would be a point of failure, and I don't want to expose my entire backend in this way.

This works fine locally, but when I run my CI on Bitrise, the build fails since these config files aren't present. I need to find a way to get these AWS and Amplify config files into the CI to be able to create my test builds.

If I am being overly cautious, and the config files are actually fine to keep in source control (i.e. not secret), please let me know. I really don't want to set up secrets as individual environment variables, since Amplify will have several secrets and endpoints for each environment I need, and it feels too messy and complicated to have a script building these config files as a CI stage.

Things I've tried:

- Creating mock config files with fake secrets that is copied in at compile time - this fails because the compile-time script still tries to copy the non-existent config files for the real environment
- Using individual environment variables as secrets in Bitrise - this is likely to work, but will be a monumental effort for my 1-dev startup to maintain
- Touching a fake config file to copy over - this works but means the actual AWS infra doesn't work in the test builds

I'll be grateful for any thoughts, suggestions or experience anyone has.

Thanks

Jacob

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Generic File Storage and the related step to download them. This will inject them into your build and you will be able to put them where they need to be before the project is compiled.